# Getting parameter name from scala function

Tags: scala, parameters, manifest

```
trait PublicApi{ 

  def sayHi(from:String,content:String) 

}
```

I know that it is impossible in java to get "from" and "content" in runtime 
but can scala manifest help me out here?? like defining

```
trait PublicApi{ 

  def sayHi(from:String,content:String)(m:Manifest) 

}
```

invoking m.methodErasure.getArgumentName(0) would return "from"

Comment: lift-json does something with paranamer that might be worth looking at. http://paranamer.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Scala "signature" *DOES* contain these parameter names, as you rightly surmise.  After all, they have to be stored *somewhere* for named/default parameters to work.  You can also use scalap to see these names.

Feel free to take a look at my preliminary work on [a reflection library](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-reflect).

It's a work in progress, and I make absolutely no guarantees as to the current feature set or correctness, but may give you some idea as to what's involved - you might even be able to use it for extracting parameter names in its current state.  This is also something I'm actively working on, so you can expect it to improve with the passage of time...

Comment: I (Somewhat worthlessly) upvoted both you and VonC, him for being most correct, and you for most useful:P

Comment: @Dylan - There's no limit on upvotes.  It's rare for me to only upvote one answer to a question.  Far more often, I'll find myself upvoting all the answers if they have something unique to contribute.

Answer (score 8):

In its current implementation, [`ClassManifest`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/ClassManifest.html) is all about [type reification](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/11/manifests-s.html), and would know nothing about parameter names.
Unless you:

- add meta data for parameter names at compile time
- or use a cut down version of **[ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)** (Java bytecode manipulation and analysis framework) to extract debug information from a class at runtime

, as [**paranamer**](http://paranamer.codehaus.org/) does (like [Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562931/monkey) mentions in the comments), you won't have any information on the parameter name (at least not before Java 8.0, even though it [was initially mentioned for Java6!](http://paulhammant.com/blog/parameter-names-for-java6-answer.html): [the proposal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000727.html) is still in progress)

Comment: As an addendum, a native Scala reflection library would have to handle this, because it is necessary to reflect named method parameters.